# How to set a variable to false when ipad orientation is changed from landscape to portrait and vice versa using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set a variable to false when iPad orientation is changed from landscape to portrait and from portrait to landscape using react and javascript.

I have two state variables isPopupOpen, isClicked set to false initially. when the button is clicked these are set to true. when the user clicks anywhere outside Popup these states isPopupOpen and isClicked are set to false.

below is my code and it works fine.

```
function Parent({setIsPopupOpen, isPopupOpen}: Props) {
    const {isClicked, setIsClicked} = React.useState(false);

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        setIsPopupOpen(!isPopupOpen);
        setIsClicked(!isClicked);
    }

    return () {
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>click me </button>
        <Popup>
            <Overlay onClick={() => {
                setIsPopupOpen(false);
                setIsClicked(false);
            }/>
        </Popup>
    }

};
```

Now the problem is when the user uses iPad in landscape mode clicks a button the popup opens, now without closing popup switches to portrait mode the popup closes on its own. now when the user clicks on the button the popup doesn't show up.

I think the problem here is, when the user switches to portrait mode, the popup closes on its own and the isClicked state value sets to false. but the isPopupOpen state value is still true.

I think since isPopupOpen is passed from other components, its value is not set to false automatically on switching to different modes. whereas isClicked state value is set to false.

How can I solve this problem? How can I set isPopupOpen to false too when the user switches modes.
does React.useEffect somehow be used for this case.

Could someone help me with this? thanks.

**EDIT:**

based on the answer provided I have tried something like this

```
const onOrientationChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsPopupOpen(false);
}, [setIsPopupOpen]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', onOrientationChange);
    return () => {
       window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', onOrientationChange);
    };
}, [onOrientationChange]);
```

But this still doesn't show the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the [`orientationchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event). Like all event handlers for events that occur outside React's domain, you'd hook it up once in a `useEffect` hook callback with no dependencies and disconnect it when you get the unmounting callback:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        // Component is being mounted, add listener
        function onOrientationChange(event) {
            // Or if you just want to set the flag false:
            setIsPopupOpen(false);
        }
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange);
        return () => {
            // Component is being unmounted, remove listener
            window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange);
        };
    },
    [] // <== No deps = only on mount
);
```

If you have any of several linting solutions in place, they may complain about your not listing `setIsPopupOpen` as a dependency in that `useEffect` call. It **should** be safe not to do so, because state setters **should** be stable (not change across the duration of a component's lifecycle). The ones from `useState` are. Since you're receiving yours via props, you'll need to be sure that that setter is indeed stable (for instance, make sure it's from `useState` in the component that's using your component).

If you just added it to the dependency array, and it gets changed regularly, you'll get spurious calls saying the orientation changed. It's possible to deal with that if you can't get that guarantee, but it's more work:

```
function Parent({setIsPopupOpen, isPopupOpen}: Props) {
    const {isClicked, setIsClicked} = React.useState(false);
    const [angle, setAngle] = React.useState(window.orientation);

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        setIsPopupOpen(!isPopupOpen);
        setIsClicked(!isClicked);
    };

    React.useEffect(
        () => {
            // Component is being mounted, add listener
            function onOrientationChange(event) {
                const newAngle = window.orientation;
                if (newAngle !== angle) {
                    setAngle(newAngle);
                    setIsPopupOpen(false);
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange);
            return () => {
                // Component is being unmounted, remove listener
                window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange);
            };
        },
        [setIsPopupOpen, angle]
    );

    return () {
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>click me </button>
        <Popup>
            <Overlay onClick={() => {
                setIsPopupOpen(false);
                setIsClicked(false);
            }/>
        </Popup>
    }

};
```

---

Note that the `window.orientation` property is described as "no longer recommended" by MDN, and both the event and the property are described by the [compatibility specification](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org/). Until or unless the Sensors API happens, though, I can't imagine mobile browsers will drop support for them.

Comment: thanks but this says to add setIsPopupOpen to dependency array error  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setIsPopupOpen'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setIsPopupOpen' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: @stack_overflow - Almost immediately after posting the answer, I realized you might run into that and added the last two paragraphs above -- have you seen them? (If not, hit refresh.)

Comment: i have edited my question as what i have tried based on your answer. thanks

Comment: @stack_overflow - That doesn't answer my question of whether you saw those paragraphs. I've also added an example of dealing with a possibly-unstable `setIsPopupOpen`. We can't help you debug code we can't see, I was just working based on your analysis that you needed to set the flag `false` when the orientation changed. Please update your question with a **full, runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: sorry that i dint refresh the page and i missed it. using your answer, seems like angle is not defined. atleast it throws error on my side.

Comment: @stack_overflow - `angle` is defined on the third line: `const [angle, setAngle] = React.useState(window.orientation);` (The `.angle `on `event.target.screen.orientation.angle` looks unnecessary and like it was a typo on MDN, so I removed it from the comment as I didn't use it in the solution.)

Comment: thanks. but still the isPopupOpen is true and not set to false. so i tried debugging by logging the angle value within function orientation method. it doesnt print it. when i switch the orientation of device i expect this orientation method to be called. but it doesnt

Comment: @stack_overflow - Weird. Please update your question with a **full, runnable** minimal reproducible example demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the [<>] toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: now i changed the useEffect with oreintation method to component that has setIsPopupOpen method defined. and it prints angle to be undefined. and i am not using real ipad device for this. using chrome dev tools simulator on windows.

Comment: i have removed the check for angle within the orientation method and it works. but not knowing why window.orientation not working? could you help me understand this. thanks.